# Domain not resolving on Google Cloud DNS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-cloud-dns

Been trying to setup a new domain on Google Cloud DNS and Google Domains, but it just wont resolve.

I'm a bit of a newby to this. Domain is primer.finance. I setup the zone in Cloud DNS, added the records to Google Domains, but fails to resolve anyway.

Checked on https://dnssec-analyzer.verisignlabs.com/primer.finance# and seems to be error free too

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming but when you say "but fails to resolve anyway." you would need to give more details. Exactly what you do and which results you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm able to open `http://primer.finance/` in my web browser. **There's no issue related to DNS configuration**. Have a look at some checks below:

1. configured DNS servers for domain at the registrar side (Google Domains):

   ```
   $ whois primer.finance | grep "Name Server"
   Name Server: ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com
   Name Server: ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com
   Name Server: ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com
   Name Server: ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com
   ```

   I assume that records above are correct because your website is reachable.
2. `NS` records for domain requested from `8.8.8.8` and `1.1.1.1`:

   ```
   $ dig NS primer.finance @8.8.8.8
   ...
   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   primer.finance.         21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
   primer.finance.         21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
   primer.finance.         21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com.
   primer.finance.         21599   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.
   ...

   $ dig NS primer.finance @1.1.1.1
   ...
   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   primer.finance.         21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com.
   primer.finance.         21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e2.googledomains.com.
   primer.finance.         21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e3.googledomains.com.
   primer.finance.         21600   IN      NS      ns-cloud-e4.googledomains.com.
   ...
   ```
3. domain name resolve requested from `8.8.8.8` and `1.1.1.1`:

   ```
   $ dig A primer.finance @8.8.8.8
   ...
   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   primer.finance.         299     IN      A       35.228.29.215
   ...

   $ dig A primer.finance @1.1.1.1
   ...
   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   primer.finance.         300     IN      A       35.228.29.215
   ...

   $ dig A www.primer.finance @8.8.8.8
   ...
   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   www.primer.finance.     299     IN      CNAME   primer.finance.
   primer.finance.         299     IN      A       35.228.29.215
   ...

   $ dig A www.primer.finance @1.1.1.1
   ...
   ;; ANSWER SECTION:
   www.primer.finance.     300     IN      CNAME   primer.finance.
   primer.finance.         300     IN      A       35.228.29.215
   ...
   ```
4. web server response:

   ```
   $ curl -I http://primer.finance
   HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   Date: Fri, 12 Jun 2020 11:01:45 GMT
   Server: Apache
   X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
   Cache-Control: max-age=0, no-cache
   Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
   ```
5. domain propagation at [dnsmap.io](https://dnsmap.io/), [dnschecker.org](https://dnschecker.org/) [whatsmydns.net](https://www.whatsmydns.net/) also looks good.

The only problem I found is wrong SSL certificate:

```
...
Issued To:

Common Name (CN)    www.example.com
Organization (O)    Bitnami
Organizational Unit (OU)    Certificate generated at boot time

Issued By:
Common Name (CN)    www.example.com
Organization (O)    Bitnami
Organizational Unit (OU)    Certificate generated at boot time
....
```

You should reply this test certificate with the proper one that was issued for your domain. Also, something wrong with switching between pages of your site: at some pages domain name was replaced by IP.

**Your issue could be related to [domain propagation time](https://www.hostgator.com/help/article/when-will-my-domain-start-working-propagation)** (accordingly to the [documentation](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/3290309?hl=en) it could take up to 48 hours after last change and it'll be self resolved) **or local caches on your computer** (try to check your web site from other computer or phone and via mobile Internet if possible).

Comment: `whois` is not the tool to use for DNS problems, and there is no "DNS propagation" as updates are not top down. Also if you want to troubleshoot things properly you need to query authoritative servers first to get records, not recursive ones.

Comment: Thanks! From my practical experience `whois` is a good tool to check DNS servers configuration at the registrar side. As I can see from this question, *@Paco* changed DNS servers for his domain from default that he had with Google Domains to Google Cloud DNS and, as result, there should be DNS propagation because `NS` records were updated (and it was in progres when I checked). You're right about query to authoritative servers, but Google Cloud DNS runs on the same infrastructure with Google Public DNS `8.8.8.8` so it's quite close for quick check in this case.

Comment: "to check DNS servers configuration at the registrar side. " this is not needed/has no meaning. Registrars are just there to forward NS records to the registry. As such they do not have any active role during DNS resolution afterwards... except of course if they are also the DNS provider, but it is clearly a different and separate job.

Comment: "there should be DNS propagation " There is NO DNS propagation as the DNS is not a top down protocol. Changes do not get pushed to other nameservers, changes are acquired by recurise nameservers when they pull for that information because they either do not have it or what they have in their cache has outlived the TTL.

Comment: "but Google Cloud DNS runs on the same infrastructure with Google Public DNS 8.8.8.8 so it's quite close for quick check in this case." This is both irrelevant and you making assumption about how Google manage its network. Authoritative and recursive nameservers are two completely different things even if they both use the same DNS protocol and one has to carefully understand this difference and do proper troubleshooting (by first querying authoritatives ones and then only recursive ones). So I will remain in disagreement with your "it's quite close for quick check".